# querySelector returned empty element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem that when my code auto refreshes after I saved the file on VS Code, `theText` and `theBtn` returns the targeted elements and the page displays the content and everything works fine. But whenever I refresh the page manually, the page displays the content, but when I clicked `theBtn` element to expand the text, the `theText` and `theBtn` becomes empty and the page failed with an error saying "cannot read property of undefined".

I have been trying to find why, but I could not. Someone please help.
Thank you.

```
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import places from '../data/places';


const Tours = () => {
return (
    <>
        <div className="my-20 mx-auto bg-blue-100 " style={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <h1 className="text-5xl capitalize text-center font-semibold">our tours</h1>
            <hr className="w-20 place-self-center mx-auto border-2 mb-12 mt-2 border-green-600" />
            <Tuor cTime={new Date().getTime().toString()} />
        </div>
    </>
)
}

const Tuor = (props) => {

const [tuors, setTours] = useState(places);

 const theText = document.querySelectorAll(".theText")
 const theBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".theBtn")
        console.log(theText);
        console.log(theBtn);


const expandText = (index) => {

    if (theBtn[index].innerHTML === "read more") {
        theText[index].style.maxHeight = "50rem";
        theBtn[index].innerHTML = "show less";
    } else if (theBtn[index].innerHTML === "show less") {
        theText[index].style.maxHeight = "6rem";
        theBtn[index].innerHTML = "read more";

    }
}

const removePlace = (id) => {
    const newTours = tuors.filter((place) => {
        return place.id !== id;
    });
    setTours(newTours);
}
return (
    <>
        {
            tuors.map((place, index) => {
                let price = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(place.price);
               
                return (
                    <>
                        <div key={index} className="flex flex-col w-2/4 mx-auto bg-white shadow-2xl mb-10">

                            <div>
                                <img src={place.image} alt={place.title} />
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex mt-10">
                                <div className="flex justify-start w-3/4 pl-10">
                                    <p className="tracking-widest capitalize font-bold">{place.title}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="flex justify-end w-1/4 pr-10"><p className="bg-blue-50 tracking-wider p-1 rounded-lg font-bold text-blue-400">N{price}</p></div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="my-5 px-10 py-2">
                                <p className="text-gray-500 theText">{place.description}</p><button className="text-blue-500 capitalize theBtn" onClick={() => expandText(index)}>read more</button>
                            </div>
                            <button className="ring-1 ring-red-600 text-red p-1 rounded-sm w-48 mx-auto capitalize my-12" onClick={() => removePlace(place.id)}>not interested</button>
                        </div>

                    </>
                )
            })
        }
    </>
)
}


export default Tours;
```

Comment: what is id of place?

Comment: id of place is a number (1 through 9). the imported places module is an array of objects

Comment: Hey, can u pls create a sandbox of the code for better understanding? Here, codesandbox.io/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-lichterman-y93n5?file=/src/tuors.js here is the link to the code on condesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelectorAll` as it is giving an `object` instead of `array of elements` at the initial render.

I find this behavior really weird, but when I read about it, I got to know about

> Because querySelectorAll() returns a list that is static from the moment it is called, its list of items cannot be updated thereafter even if changes are made to the DOM dynamically. Contrast this to getElementsByClassName(), which returns matching sets of elements at any given moment it is called. If you are making changes to the DOM on the fly, the list returned by getElementsByClassName() will be updated dynamically.

- `querySelectorAll` returns `static NodeList object`
- `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTML Collection` which is dynamic

Here is the link to code: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wood-slqs4?file=/src/tuors.js

`You can read more about differences at` https://unicorntears.dev/posts/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname/

Comment: Thank you so much. It really worked. It would've been very difficult for me to figure it out. Thanks once again for the link to read the difference. I sure will.

Comment: Good to hear that it really helped. Welcome : )

Comment: I can see you used `useEffect()` empty, why was that? And the `useRef()` cnt.current I `console.log` it out it returned 1 everytime I run the code. Cant you please why you used that? Thanks

Comment: I was debugging so I added it. No need to use it. You can remove it.

Comment: Okay thank you for kind and helpful responses.